# Login form in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin7

I am creating a new login form using Vaadin. I have 2 classes as below:

LoginUI.java is the base class which inokes the LoginView.java containing the code for Login page. Its still a prototype and have not implemented the listeners. But, when I deploy and run on tomcat I see blank page without anythign displayed. Can someone please help?

**LoginUI.java - Base class**

```java
 public class LoginUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = LoginUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        LoginView view  = new LoginView();
        setContent(view);
    }
}
```

**LoginView.java**

```java
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements ClickListener  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Label feedback;

    private final TextField username;
    private final TextField password;

    private final Button registerBtn;
    private final Button loginBtn;
    private HorizontalLayout layout= new HorizontalLayout();

    public LoginView() {

        feedback = new Label();
        layout.addComponent(feedback);

        username = new TextField("Username");
        username.setWidth("100%");
        username.setNullRepresentation("");
        layout.addComponent(username);

        password = new TextField("Password");
        password.setWidth("100%");
        password.setNullRepresentation("");
        layout.addComponent(password);

        loginBtn = new Button("Sign In");
        layout.addComponent(loginBtn);

        registerBtn = new Button("Register");
        layout.addComponent(registerBtn);
        setSizeFull();
    }


    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        if (event.getButton().equals(loginBtn)) {
            String username = (String) this.username.getValue();
            String password = (String) this.password.getValue();
            Notification.show("User Present");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your LoginView is a `VerticalLayout` and in it you are using a `HorizontalLayout` and adding all your components to it. But you never at the `HorizontalLayout` (layout) to the  `VerticalLayout`. So ether add your ad it like this:

```
addCompontent(layout);
```

But then I don't see why LoginView is a `VerticalLayout`. 
Or don't user the `HorizontalLayout`:

```
public LoginView() {

  feedback = new Label();
  addComponent(feedback);

  username = new TextField("Username");
  username.setWidth("100%");
  username.setNullRepresentation("");
  addComponent(username);

  password = new TextField("Password");
  password.setWidth("100%");
  password.setNullRepresentation("");
  addComponent(password);

  loginBtn = new Button("Sign In");
  addComponent(loginBtn);

  registerBtn = new Button("Register");
  addComponent(registerBtn);
  setSizeFull();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that Vaadin 8 has a built-in `LoginForm`.

Here's how to use it with Vaadin CDI:

```
import com.vaadin.cdi.CDIView;
import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.ui.LoginForm;

@CDIView(LoginView.VIEW_NAME)
public class LoginView extends LoginForm implements View {

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent viewChangeEvent) {
        addLoginListener(loginEvent -> onLogin(loginEvent));
    }

    private void onLogin(LoginEvent loginEvent) {
        final String username = loginEvent.getLoginParameter("username");
        final String password = loginEvent.getLoginParameter("password");

        try {
            JaasAccessControl.login(username, password);
            Notification.show("Login successful");

        } catch (ServletException e) {
            final String message = "User '" + username + "' login failed";
            Notification.show(message, ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Full example [here](https://github.com/mrts/vaadin-javaee-clinic-patient-queue-example/blob/master/vaadin-javaee-clinic-patient-queue-example-ui/src/main/java/com/clinicpatientqueueexample/doctorsoffice/LoginView.java).

A login component is available for Vaadin 13+ as well, see [here](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login).